# Data.table do differenced operation with date R

Tags: r, data.table, lapply

Hi I have a dataset in data.table format. Lets call this dtA:

```
Date    Company    Data
200012    compA       3
200012    compB       4
200012    compC       7
200101    compA       1
200101    compB       2
200101    compC       3
200102    compA       2
200102    compB       4
200102    compC       1
```

I want to do for each date, for each company, I want to do substraction in between.

So the end result will be:

```
Date    Company    Data
200102    compA       1
200102    compB       2
200102    compC      -2
200101    compA      -2
200101    compB      -2
200101    compC      -4
```

I wrote a long winded and bulky code to do this, is there anyway I can use the lapply function within data.table?
I seems dont understand how lapply be used inside data.table. when lapply does not have iterator in it I cannot loop through date...

This is my code:

```
date=as.data.table(c("200012","200101", "200102"))
comp=as.data.table(c("compA","compB","compC"))
result=NA
date=date[-order(date)] #so it go decenting order

for (i in 1:(nrow(date)-1)){
    d1=date[i]
    d2=date[i+1]


    dtA1=dtA[Date==d1][order(Company)]
    dtA2=dtA[Date==d2][order(Company)]
    ans.temp=merge(dtA1,dtA2, on=c("Date","Company"))
    ans.temp=ans.temp[,Data := Data.x - Data.y, by="Company"]
    ans.temp=ans.temp[,-c(3,4,5)]


    if (is.NA(result)[1]){
        result=ans.temp
    } else{
        result=rbind(result, ans.temp)
    }

}
```

Comment: `dtA[, list(diff = diff(Data), Date = Date[-1]), by = Company]`? No loops or applies needed.

Comment: Many thanks Greg I learn one new thing again! diff()!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need loops or applies, just use `diff` by the Company group:

```
setkey(dtA, Date, Company)
dtA[, list(diff = diff(Data), Date = Date[-1]), by = Company]
#    Company diff   Date
# 1:   compA   -2 200101
# 2:   compA    1 200102
# 3:   compB   -2 200101
# 4:   compB    2 200102
# 5:   compC   -4 200101
# 6:   compC   -2 200102
```

---

Using this data:

```
dtA = fread("Date    Company    Data
200012    compA       3
200012    compB       4
200012    compC       7
200101    compA       1
200101    compB       2
200101    compC       3
200102    compA       2
200102    compB       4
200102    compC       1")
```